# PHP $this-> is not properly setting a variable

Tags: php, oop, curl, methods, this

EDIT2: 
FULL WORKING CODE

```
<?php
include_once('config.php');
function getAccountCredentials(){
        //here we are getting our account credentias from the accountConfiguration class
        $accountCredentials = new accountConfiguration;
        $account_id = $accountCredentials->account_id;
        $api_accesskey = $accountCredentials->api_accesskey;
        $accountArray = array('account_id'=>$account_id, 'api_accesskey'=>$api_accesskey);
        $transactionRequestParameters = json_encode(array('data'=>$accountArray), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
        $decode = json_decode($transactionRequestParameters, true, 4);
        $credentials = array_shift($decode);
        return $credentials;
        }
function getBaseURL($val){
  $baseURL = new baseURL;
  $url = $baseURL->url;
  return $url.$val;
}

class apiRequest{
  private $url;
    private $params = array();
  public $response = array();
  public function setUrl($val) {
    $baseUrl = getBaseURL($val);
    $this->url = $baseUrl;
  }

  public function setAccountCredentials(){
    //This calls our account credentials function.
    $account_info = getAccountCredentials();
    //Here We're setting our account information to variables.
    $account_id=$account_info['account_id'];
    $api_accesskey = $account_info['api_accesskey'];
    //Here I am setting the account information to the params variable.
    $this->setParam('account_id', $account_id);
    $this->setParam('api_accesskey', $api_accesskey);
  }
  public function setParam($pname, $value) {
        $this->params[$pname] = $value;
    }
    public function setParams($params) {
        if (is_array($params)) {
            $this->params = array_merge($this->params, $params);
        } else {
            die('Must send array');
        }
    }
  public function sendRequest(){
    $pdata = $this->params;
    $url = $this->url;
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $pdata);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $res = curl_exec($ch);
    $response_decode = json_decode($res, true);
    var_export($this->response = $response_decode);
    }
    public function ReportingServices($request_parameters){
        $api_url = "REDACTED";
        $request = new apiRequest;
        $request->setAccountCredentials();
        $request->setUrl($api_url);
        $request_information = array('response_format'=>'JSON');
        $request ->setParams($request_information);
        $request ->setParams($request_parameters);
        $request->sendRequest();
      }
  }

$request = new apiRequest;
$values = array ('start_date'=>'2015-04-15','end_date'=>'2015-04-18');
$request->ReportingServices($values);
?>
```

What I'm trying to accomplish:

Now, if I add this function to my method.

```
public function getResponse(){
return $this->response;
var_export($this->response);
}
```

Then edit `sendRequest()` to do the following:

```
public function sendRequest(){
$pdata = $this->params;
$url = $this->url;
$ch = curl_init($url);
      curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $pdata);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $res = curl_exec($ch);
$response_decode = json_decode($res, true);
$this->response = $response_decode;
}
```

Then call my method this way:

```
$request = new apiRequest;
$values = array ('start_date'=>'2015-04-15','end_date'=>'2015-04-18');
$request->ReportingServices($values);
$response = $request->getResponse();
var_export($response);
```

The `var_export` on `$response` does not work.

Comment: It works fine for me. Did you reinitialize the class before calling the second function or otherwise reset the response variable?

Comment: There isn't any re-initialization going on. This is the code I'm using to instantiate the class when making the request. 
`$request = new apiRequest;`
`$request->sendRequest($values);`
`$response = $request->getResponse();`

Comment: Can you post a full example where it is not working?

Comment: I've posted the code I am using to use the method.

Comment: The first code doesn't work either. Like I said, please test your code to make sure it does what you think it does before posting.

Comment: I'm trying to keep the question compact instead of posting ~300 lines of code. I'll make it a little smaller and I'll edit it with the results. 

Thanks!

Comment: @Anonymous I have added the full working code, and what I am trying to get working.

Comment: Answered. Just make sure to do the same in the future with examples (maybe after cutting down the code a little to remove unnecessary parts).

Comment: @Anonymous Will do, I thought I had in the beginning, but I see now I picked the wrong parts to try and omit. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you do indeed reinitialize the class.

```
$request = new apiRequest;
// ...
public function ReportingServices($request_parameters){
    $api_url = "REDACTED";
    $request = new apiRequest;
    $request->setAccountCredentials();
    $request->setUrl($api_url);
    $request_information = array('response_format'=>'JSON');
    $request ->setParams($request_information);
    $request ->setParams($request_parameters);
    $request->sendRequest();
}
```

The two instances are not the same. They do not share any variables. You set the variable in one instance and try to get it in another, which does not work.

Comment: My apologies. I accidentally delete my semi-colon when formatting. 

As I stated, this code works when I return the values inside of the sendRequest() funciton.

Comment: Man. Thank you so much! I really appreciate all the help. Sorry for the difficulties in the beginning. I'm going to take this info and re-factor what I'm doing. That has to be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

One issue I see is that you are never setting `$params` properly. As written, your `sendRequest()` function does not take any arguments. However, it uses `$this->params` as it's data payload. This will always be an empty `array()`. So.. that leaves you with one of three options:

1. make sure that `sendRequest()` actually takes the args, and ditch using `$this->params`
2. create a setter for `$this->params` and call it before `sendRequest()`
3. Use a constructor function (`__contruct`) that will set `$this->params` when you create `apiRequest`

Comment: I'm doing a poor job of putting this up here. I have functions that use sendRequest() and within these functions I use a setter for params called setParams() and then I use sendRequest(). 

All my params are setting correctly and I can even reach the API and get a response. The response just simply does not set if I use $this->response = $response_decode. But I can var_export that and I have my response and everything works.